# Fix the output of uptime

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, uptime

So I've been experimenting with Bash not too long ago, and I want to manipulate the output from the "uptime" command. I managed to change the output of up x minutes to 0:05 for example if the up time is 5 minutes, but the rest of the things disappear.

What method should I use to also display the time, the amount of users and its load average without affecting my current up time output.

This is the desired output: `21:08:13 up 0:10, 3 users, load average: 0.30, 0.30, 0.25`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

since="`uptime --since`"
start="`date --date "$since" '+%s'`"
now="`date '+%s'`"
sec=$((now-start))

days=$((sec/(60*60*24)))
sec=$((sec-days*(60*60*24)))

hr=$((sec/(60*60)))
sec=$((sec-hr*(60*60)))

min=$((sec/60))
sec=$((sec-min*60))

rest="$(uptime | perl -npe'{s/(.*,\s+)(\d+\s+user)/$2/}')"

printf "%d(days), %02d:%02d:%02d(hms), %s\n" $days $hr $min $sec "$rest"
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
0(days), 00:34:00(hms), 3 users, load average: 0.09, 0.14, 0.14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is with Perl. This is just one line added and the `printf` line altered:

```
rest="$(uptime | perl -npe'{s/(.*,\s+)(\d+\s+user)/$2/}')"

printf "%d(days), %02d:%02d:%02d(hms), %s\n" $days $hr $min $sec "$rest"
```

Result:

```
 00:55:21 up 10 days,  2:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.05, 0.06, 0.07
```

Note there's one field still missing, compare:

```
$ ./uptime.bash
10(days), 02:45:06(hms), 1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.04
$ uptime
 01:02:10 up 10 days,  2:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.03, 0.04
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work unfortunately. It only gives the following: "0(days), 00:00:00(hms)," Like literally 00000. But this still doesn't give me a clue/idea on how to fix my problem.

Comment: @Genki.- It needs all of the preceding lines from your question. I just posted what's changed.

Comment: Ohh woops, my bad. I'll give it a try @Tomasz

Comment: Yeah indeed, there is a difference with the 1st field. Is it changeable?

Comment: @Genki.- It looks like the current time on my laptop.

Comment: @Genki.- You can take it from `date` if needed.

Comment: @Genki.- Or `uptime` again.

Comment: I've updated my answer and I will update its result too. It still doesn't seem to give the desired output even after experimenting it myself

Comment: -short comment......

Comment: @Genki.- What comment do you want?

Comment: Ah nothing @Tomasz I think I fixed it, thanks for the help!